# random number in multi threading not working

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, random, datatable

please examine my code below :

```
Public Class tier1

Dim rnd As New System.Random()



Function build1(ByVal dt As DataTable) As String
    Try
        For i = 0 To 4
            For ix As Integer = 0 To till Step 4
                lstrn.Add(rnd.Next(ix, ix + 4))
            Next

            Dim cntx As Integer = 0

            For Each x As Integer In lstrn
                If (i = 0) Then
                    If (article(x).Split(ChrW(10)).Length > 2) Then
                        If (article(x).Split(ChrW(10))(0).Length > 300) Then
                            first.Add(article(x).Split(ChrW(10))(0))
                            cntx = cntx + 1
                            If (cntx = 25) Then
                                Exit For
                            End If
                        End If
                    End If
                End If


            lstrn.Clear()
        Next

        Dim fi as String = "{"

        For dx As Integer = 0 To first.Count - 2
            fi = fi & w.spinl(first(dx), "light") & "|"
        Next

        fi = fi & "}"

        Return fi
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try

End Function

End Class
```

Now see my calling code :

```
Dim w As WaitCallback = New WaitCallback(AddressOf beginscn)

For var As Integer = 1 To NumericUpDown1.Value
            Dim param(1) As Object
            param(0) = lst
            param(1) = var
            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(w, param)
        Next

sub 

sub beginscn()
    Dim scntxt As String = t1.buildtier1(dt)
end sub
```

Now understand what i give and what i want. Suppose i pass a datatable like this :

```
1,abcd,34,5
2,adfg,34,5
3,fhjrt,34,5
4,rtitk,34,5
```

What i want is {abcd|adfg|fhjrt|rtitk} and this sequence should be random everytime. Since i pass like 50-100 values and exit loop at 25 each output should have a different sequence of 25 strings in {|} format but it does not work like that. Everytime i get same sequence.

Can anyone explain why does it do like that and any possible solution for this problem?

Note : I have already tried shuffling datatable just before queuing it but still it does not work.

Comment: It's hard to understand what you are trying to do

Comment: I'm not a VB.net programmer but my hunch is you're not setting the random number seed to something like the current time in milliseconds.  There are no such things as truly random numbers in computers so instead it's a maths function that gives a sequence of unrelated numbers starting from this seed.  If you don't set the seed it will default to a set number therefore give you the same sequence each time.

Comment: Don't forget, random is not thread safe. Put a lock around it.

Comment: What's in the `article()` array?  That's where the problem seems to be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The random object is not thread safe. You could work around this by creating separate instances of the random object in each thread and use the thread ID to generate the 
seed.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683183%28VS.85%29.aspx